# Delete Kanji Characters in Memo field

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a memo field in MS Access with values that contain both Kanji (Japanese) and Roman characters.

Is there a function I can call or technique that I can use to essentially remove all the Kanji characters and just leave the Roman characters?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what MS Access version?

Comment: I'm using Access 2007

Comment: Those characters didn't mean anything important, right?

Comment: will you please showup the content and the required output for sample?

Comment: yes they are not important. as in literally just delete the kanji characters and keep the roman ones.

Comment: It might be more work than a single (ideal) command, but what if you: 1) export your MS Access database to an Excel file 2) then, in Excel, run some sort of macro ([maybe something like this](http://www.asap-utilities.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/13/macro-keep-only-ascii-characters-32-127/)) to clear out the extra characters... and then import your Excel file back into a new MS Access database?